# I have 3 rules on .htaccess that is not function at same time Friendly URLs, Force HTTPS and Not WWW

Tags: .htaccess

## Friendly URLs

---

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?url=$1
```

## Forcing 'https://'

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !'"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [L]
```

## Suppressing `www.` at the beginning of URLs

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I'm using CloudFlare and when I activate all, it's return a loop.

Comment: I need add both? Now I change to https, because before it's already changed to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Glad to know. You can replace `302` by `301` to make it permanent redirect.